# Can we detect sandwich bot transaction while its in Mempool

Tags: bsc, txpool, bot

I need to check if for a particular token transactions is there any sandwich bot transaction or sandwich attack.

Answer (score 0):

Because the sandwich attack is done by the block producer, it cannot be detected in the mempool.

Comment: So you mean miner do this

Comment: Yes miners do it